# AWS Cloudwatch Logs to HTTP end point

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services

Is any library available in Node JS or Javascript to retrieve logs from cloudwatch and send to http endpoint?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use the AWS sdk for this as the other person suggested. You should use the Cloudwatch Logs subscription feature to do this.

The only method to get log data via the API alone is GetLogEvents. This apparently was designed to get small amounts of data out, it has a cap of around 10 queries per second across the entire account.

Instead the service includes a subscription feature where log data in a log group is delivered to a scalable service such as Kinesis, Firehose, or for your use case Lambda

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2015/09/near-real-time-processing-of-amazon-cloudwatch-logs-with-aws-lambda/

using the lambda blueprint for cloudwatch logs you get something that will consume data in real time as it's available from cloudwatch logs and unpack the compressed JSON document containing log events. Then just simply post the contents to your endpoint.

You don't need to run any additional processes yourself and it scales arbitrarily to the size of your data. There is a limit for Lambda as well - 100 concurrent functions running at once, which I estimated was equivalent to 300 GetLogEvents per second - but if you fill out the lambda limit increase they're very eager to lift that for you.

Another options is to use Kinesis and Lambda. The direct integration of logs to lambda will drop data if you function throws an exception due to the way lambda works. However if you put a Kinesis in the middle you get up to 7 days of durable retry queue that will only checkpoint when your function succeeds. Additionally you can tweak the batching to reduce chattiness.

People are often reluctant to use Kinesis due to cost but it's crazy cheap. For $14/month/shard you can pump tons of data through it and it just works. The only caveat is you need to put an alarm on your Kinesis stream throughput at around 700kb/s to know to split your Kinesis shards.

But if durable delivery isn't critical to you just go straight lambda.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're looking for the [AWS SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-node-js/). Just out of curiosity, how come you want to fetch logs from CloudWatch and send to an HTTP Endpoint? It sounds more efficient and logical for your application to do that itself.